# What is the difference between classification and pattern recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, computer-science, deep-learning, supervised-learning

Could someone explain the difference between classification and pattern recognition as simply as possible or direct me to the right place?!

Answer (score 4):

Pattern recognition is a generic term for the ability to recognize regularities or patterns in data. A more generic one is machine learning.
Classification is an example of pattern recognition, where a model devides the data into classes.

More specific from left to right:
Machine Learning > Pattern Recognition > Classification > Linear Classification > SVM

Answer (score 4):

There are many types of [Pattern Recognition algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition#Algorithms), and Classification algorithms is one among them, i.e. **not all pattern recognition algorithms are classifier algorithms.**

To qualify as a classifier, an algorithm needs to **map an input data point to a category among a set of categories** (or labels, or classes)

As an example of a pattern recognition algorithm that **isn't a classifier**, consider the k-means algorithm, which is a **clustering** algorithm. When the k-means algorithm runs it finds patterns in your data and try to splits into distinct *clusters*.

[image]

<sub>Image from Wikipedia page of [k-means algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)</sub>

If you wish to attach a label to an input to classify it into one of the clusters (e.g. returned by the k-means), you may e.g. use a classifier algorithm like [k-nearest neighbors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) (k-NN), which takes an input and as output predicts the cluster to which it is classified.